# How come my script can't check the database for similar usernames?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to check the database for a taken username when the user signs up. The connection to the database works fine as a similar password will be added to the table.

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$s = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "$username"';

$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num == 1) {
    echo "Username is taken";
}else {
```

[table for users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UhBG.png)

It goes to the else and adds the username to the database anyways. I have checked to make sure there isn't more than one username, although a greater than sign would work better anyway. any ideas?

Comment: Possibly there are 2 or more *same* usernames in your db?

Comment: Sorry, I do have prepared statements for the other part and was planning on it once I could get this part to actually work. Thanks for reminding though.

Comment: `if ($num == 1)` ... if there are already 2 or more *same* usernames in you db, this condition will always default to the `else`. So ensure that previous test cases didn't add duplicate usernames to your db.

Comment: yeah at the moment the usernames I tried (and deleted afterward) only had one of themselves in the table. The result could only be 0 or 1.

Comment: @Wenis then `echo` out `$num`. What's its value?

Comment: I'm wondering why you're using `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code must be using parameter binding to send the value of `$username` to the database, otherwise `"$username"` is treated as a literal string. It will also protect your from SQL injections.

It would probably be better to create a UNIQUE key on that column instead. If you want to do it in the application layer for whatever reason, you can fetch the result and use that.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();

if ($result) {
    echo "Username is taken";
} else {
    // No such username in the database yet
}
```

This is not going to be very efficient, so we can simplify it using `COUNT(1)`. It will return a single value containing the number of matching rows.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$usernameTaken = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row()[0];

if ($usernameTaken) {
    echo "Username is taken";
} else {
    // No such username in the database yet
}
```

For more explanation see https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/check_value

Comment: I posted a comment under their question on why they're using `password_hash()`. I think you might be chased down a rabbit hole here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think this is just part of the code which follows. In the else part they would create new account

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just tested it out and it works. The two lines related to password are not relevant for the answer, so I will remove them.

Comment: I don't question your answer :) I was just unsure as to their inclusion of `password_hash()`.

Comment: I wonder why my first comment asking if you were 100% sure was deleted.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I flagged it as not longer needed. :D I don't like comments loitering around. If they don't add anything I flag them.

Comment: Thing is, when something is missing and there's more comments after, people will wonder why the other comments where the original context/question was lost. I don't know why you did that.

Comment: The other comments are still relevant even without our first two comments. I didn't flag others as they add value, but the first one and my reply became obsolete once I tested it out and you expanded on your point. Now by talking about our comments we of course added twice as much noise, so my comment cleanup efforts failed.

Answer (score -2):

**$s = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "$username"';**

You are using double quote inside single quote so there is no interpolation happening. Change the order to

$s = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}'";

Comment: This should be addressed by using parameter binding.